Notational confusion about the diagonalization of matrix
The diagonalization of a matrix $M$ is often described as follows:

Let $M$ be a matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and the corresponding
eigenvectors $x_i$ i.e. $M x_i = \lambda_i x_i$, and  $X$ is the
matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors $x_i$. One can write
\begin{equation}   MX =  M \left[x_1  \dots x_n \right] =
 \left[\lambda_1 x_1 \dots \lambda_n x_n  \right] = [\lambda_1 x_1
 \dots \lambda_n x_n ]  = [x_1 \dots x_n] diag.(\lambda_1 \dots
 \lambda_n) = X \Lambda  \end{equation}
This gives the diagonalisation $\Lambda = X^{-1} M X$.

I am not able to understand the notation notation
$$M \left[x_1  \dots x_n \right] =
 \left[\lambda_1 x_1 \dots \lambda_n x_n  \right] \qquad (1)$$
Are we just taking matrix $M$ inside $[~~~~]$ and hitting each column vector $x_k$? I am not familiar with such matrix multiplication.
I understand that given (say) $M = \begin{pmatrix} m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ and $x_k = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta  \end{pmatrix}$ the matrix multiplication can be written in (not so common) the following manner:
$$\begin{pmatrix} m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta  \end{pmatrix} = \alpha \begin{pmatrix} m_{11} \\ m_{21} \end{pmatrix} +  \beta \begin{pmatrix} m_{21} \\ m_{22} \end{pmatrix}$$
But I am not quite sure how can one justify $(1)$.

Yes, you multiply the matrix with each vector. Assume dimension of $M$ is $n \times n$, and the dimension of $x$. to be $n \times 1$. Then $Mx$ is just a vector.

If $x_k=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_k\\beta_k\end{pmatrix}$ then
$[x_1\dots x_n]$ means $\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1&\dots&\alpha_n\\beta_1&\dots&\beta_n\end{pmatrix}$.

$[x_1  \dots x_n]$ is obviously the matrix whose columns are the vectors $x_i,.$ The notation (1) perfectly fits into the principle (that you probably know) that a matrix multiplication is nothing else than a bunch of matrix vector multiplications.

Ordinary matrix multiplication can be thought of in this manner. For two $n\times n$ square matrices $M,X$, if we write $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ for the columns of $X$, then we have that
$$ MX = M[x_1,\ldots,x_n] = [Mx_1,\ldots, Mx_n], $$
i.e. $MX$ is just the matrix with columns $Mx_1, \ldots, Mx_n$.
Since the $\lambda_i$ are just the eigenvalues for the corresponding eigenvectors $x_i$ of $M$, we thus have that the usual matrix product $MX$ is exactly this matrix $[\lambda_1 x_1, \ldots, \lambda_n x_n]$.

Let $C = M[x_1,\dots,x_n] \implies C_{ij} = M(i,:)x_j$. Fixing j, go through all $i$, now I hope you're convinced why we can treat  as a whole and push it inside $[    ]$ to hit $x_j$, to get the $j$-th column vector of $C$.
